# How to explain that ((P-->Q)&P) does not logically imply that " P logically implies Q"? ( On a false interpretation of modus ponens).

Tags: logic, soft-question, propositional-calculus

Context: reflexion on a possible way to misunderstand " modus ponens" as meaning ( erroneously) : If [(P-->Q) and P] then (P logically implies Q).

---

Sure, a truth table shows that [ (P-->Q) & P ] logically implies that " P materially implies Q".

Indeed the formula " [ (P-->Q) & P ] --> ( P-->Q) " is valid,

or ( equivalently " [ (P-->Q) & P ] ==> ( P-->Q) " is correct ( with " ==>"

meaning (tauto)logically implies" )

[image]

But I can't manage to explain, using a truth table or another method, that

[ (P-->Q) & P ] ==> ( P==>Q) is not correct,

with " ==> " still meaning (tauto)logically implies .

***Which valuation would make [ (P-->Q)&P] true and (P==>Q) false?***

I'm not even sure that this way of putting the question is correct.

Comment: Why you do not format the formulas appropriately ? The issue is clear in this case, where you are playing with arrows that (itr seems) have different meanings...

Comment: With P ==> Q do you mean $P \vDash Q$ ? i.e. $Q$ is a *logical* (or : *semantical*) *consequence* of $P$ ?

Comment: Are $P$ and $Q$ formulas or propositional variables ?

Comment: Yes. I use this symbol in order to distinguish logical implication and material implication.

Comment: This helps. Thanks. Maybe I could say, in order to explain the mistake I want to prevent, that " even when we are in an actual  case where "(P-->Q) & P" is true, the cases in which P is true and Q is false are still possible, and consequently, even when the antecedent is true, the consequent is not tautologically true." I know that using a truth table to test an expression involving metalogical concepts is not standard, but I would have liked to do it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression $(P → Q) ∧ P$  is a *formula* of the language while $P \vDash Q$ is not.

$\vDash$ is a symbol of the meta-language expressing a relation between formulas, while $(P → Q) ∧ P$ is an expression in the object language.

Every valuation $v$ will assign a truth value to formula; thus, with valuation $v$ such that $v(P)=\text T$ and $v(Q)=\text F$, the formula will be evaluated to $\text F$.

Obviously, with a different valuation the resulting truth value can change (except for tautologies and contradictions).

The situation is different for the relation $\vDash$. In this case we have to consider **all** valuations in order to assert that it holds or not :

> $\varphi \vDash \psi$  iff, for very valuation $v$ such that $v(\varphi)=\text T$ also $v(\psi)=\text T$.

Specifically for propositional variables $P$ and $Q$, we can **never** have $P \vDash Q$, exactly because we have the valuation $v$ such that :

> $v(P)=\text T$ and $v(Q)=\text F$.

---

We have to take care in using the expression : $(P → Q) ∧ P \vDash (P \vDash Q)$, because it is not meaningful.

It is not a formula of the language (because $\vDash$ is not part of the object language) and thus we cannot evaluate it with truth tables.

We can write an expression of the meta-language like :

> if ..., then $P \vDash Q$.

As said above, if $P$ and $Q$ are propositional variables, then $P \vDash Q$ is false.

Thus, an example of true statement (in the meta-language) involving it will be :

> > if $\vDash (P → Q) ∧ P$, then $P \vDash Q$.